# can't obtain plot of quantiles values side-by-side with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot the values of quantiles using the ggplot geom_box. My goal is to obtain side-by-side plot of treatments (T1, T2) on the x axis and plots have to be facet_wrap(feaure). What I obtain are box plot that all have same values in all graphs. Please help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(table2, aes(treatment, ymin=0, lower = 25, middle =50, upper=75, ymax=100, fill = treatment))+
    geom_boxplot(stat="identity") + 
    facet_wrap("feature",  strip.position = "right")+
    theme(panel.grid  = element_blank())
```

**DATA**

```
table2 <- structure(list(feature = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", 
"h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t"
), treatment = c("T1", "T2", "T1", "T2", "T1", "T2", "T1", "T2", 
"T1", "T2", "T1", "T2", "T1", "T2", "T1", "T2", "T1", "T2", "T1", 
"T2"), X0 = c(1L, 249L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 73L, 1L, 25L, 1L, 134L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 49L, 1L, 1L), X25 = c(1L, 546L, 1L, 372L, 
1L, 265L, 1L, 225L, 1L, 297L, 1L, 62L, 1L, 27L, 1L, 139L, 1L, 
269L, 1L, 1L), X50 = c(1, 1817, 1, 783, 3.5, 518, 1, 445, 9.5, 
366, 1, 113, 1, 75, 5.5, 262, 1, 385, 13.5, 1), X75 = c(9.25, 
2296, 4.75, 1350, 42.25, 769, 549.5, 1220, 167.25, 539, 1, 213, 
1, 573, 22, 441, 1, 941, 119.5, 1), X100 = c(91L, 2603L, 59L, 
4515L, 309L, 1162L, 858L, 1761L, 562L, 1017L, 71L, 1702L, 46L, 
1518L, 85L, 834L, 7L, 1321L, 1218L, 71L)), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: the columns containing your box plot parameters are named "X0", "X25", "X50", etc. Your code is setting the aesthetics on the values 0, 25, 50, etc. which is why they are static.

Comment: The Xs (X0, X25, X50) you see are not present in the actual table that I am using for the plot. The actual table has values identical (0, 25, 50, 75 and 100) that I specified in the ggplot.

Comment: in that case the problem is a number will always be interpreted as a numeric value, not a column name. to force it to be linked to a column name, use backticks: `aes(ymin = \`0\`, ...)` For this reason, it is not advised to have numbers as column names.

Comment: You are right. How can I change the column name in a way that r will still understand and these are not numbers but quantiles variable names and plot the way I expect. I followed your advice by adding backticks and the graphs were all empty.

Comment: run `names(table2) <- make.names(table2)` to convert names to syntactically valid names, then reference those in your `aes()` call